# Potential of a dipole with actual physical extension?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole, multipole-expansion

I think everybody here knows the equation that gives the potential of a point like dipole, but how does the field look like if you have e.g. a metal sphere with radius $R$ and a certain dipol moment, how does this potential look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer by considering the multipole expansion of a charge distribution.

The electric potential of *any localized* charge distribution can be expanded in terms of the distance (or inverse of it) from the origin to the field location in a multipole expansion. In this expansion, what you are actually doing is writing the potential of the charge distribution in terms of **ideal** multipole potentials. So, **for the regions where the expansion is valid**, the potential of **any** charge distribution that all of it's multipole moments except the dipole moment vanish is exactly that of an ideal dipole moment.

Assume in an arbitrary (localized) charge distribution, the most distant charge in the distribution is located at a radius of $r=r'$. For the potential at points with $r>r'$ you can use the equation $(1)$ and for the points with $r<r'$ you can use equation $(2)$:
$$\Phi(\mathbf{r}) = 
\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon r} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}
\left( \frac{r^{\prime}}{r} \right)^{l}
\left( \frac{4\pi}{2l+1} \right)
\sum_{m=-l}^{l} 
Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)  Y_{lm}^{*}(\theta^{\prime}, \phi^{\prime})\tag{1}$$
$$\Phi(\mathbf{r}) = 
\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon r^{\prime}} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}
\left( \frac{r}{r^{\prime}} \right)^{l}
\left( \frac{4\pi}{2l+1} \right)
\sum_{m=-l}^{l} 
Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)  Y_{lm}^{*}(\theta^{\prime}, \phi^{\prime})\tag{2}$$
or in a more compact form:
$$\Phi(\mathbf{r}) = 
\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}
\frac{r_<^{l}}{r_>^{l+1}}
\left( \frac{4\pi}{2l+1} \right)
\sum_{m=-l}^{l} 
Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)  Y_{lm}^{*}(\theta^{\prime}, \phi^{\prime})$$

So, the shape of the distribution doesn't matter, and what matters is it's multipole moments. In your example of a charged sphere with (only) dipole moment, the potential outside will be exactly a pure dipole potential, and inside, it will be constant.

Comment: but now think about the following: You have an inhomogenous electric field(for example given by an arbitrary charge distribution 1m away from the sphere) and the sphere(no charge but dipole moment) is in this electric field. How do you evaluate the potential energy of this configuration? Cause you need some distance to do this. You could just take the center of the sphere as a reference point, but is this always the correct way to do this?

Comment: @ Mostafa do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: @Lipschitz I don't understand the problem. To find the energy you just need the field everywhere.

Comment: @Lipschitz If you want to calculate the interaction energy of a dipole and a field, you can use $U=-\vec p.\vec E$. But if the sphere is conducting, because it's charges always have a constant potential (on a equipotential surface) no work is done on the charges.

Comment: The thing is the following: Imagine that you have two metallic spheres and you have one layer on each sphere that carries an asymmetrically distributed charge, so this charge will cause that in those two spheres, there will be a dipole moment. Now I want to calculate the full interaction energy of this arrangement. I thought about the following:  1.) The coulomb-repulsion between the two charge distributions(they are equally charged) 2.) The dipole repulsion between the two metal spheres and 3.) The interaction energy between the dipoles and the charges. Is this idea of doing it correct?

Comment: Maybe we could have a chat if this is possible, for a better discussion.

Comment: ,in this case you have to open the discussion, since I do not have enough points

Comment: I agree, since I don't get your question clearly! [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9933/room-for-lipschitz-and-mostafa) is the room!

Comment: would you mind discussing with me an easier task in our room?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Sure, but currently I'm on a short trip; I will be there as soon as I can.