# Potential of arbitrary charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, charge, gauss-law

Imagine this:

You have a sphere of air where you have no charge and around this sphere you have a charge distribution $\rho(r,\theta,\phi)$. (For instance, this could be $\rho(r,\theta,\phi)=e^{-r}$)
Now my question is: What is the most general equation that will give me the potential inside the sphere?-You can use that we have azimuthal symmetry. I am just interested in the equation.

Probably this will contain a series with Legendre Polynomials and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The electric potential $\Phi$ is defined through the following relation:

$$\mathbf{E}=-\nabla \Phi\tag{1}$$

Now consider a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ such that:

$$\nabla.\mathbf{F}=D$$
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{F}=\mathbf{C}$$

According to Helmholtz theorem, if the divergence $D(\mathbf{r})$ and the curl $\mathbf{C(r)}$ are specified and **if they both go to zero faster than $\dfrac{1}{ r^2}$ as $r\to \infty$,** and if $\mathbf{F(r)}$ goes to zero as  $r\to \infty$ then $\mathbf{F}$ is uniquely given by

$$\mathbf{F}=-\nabla U+ \nabla \times \mathbf{W}$$ 
where

$$U(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{D(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}d^3r'\tag{2}$$
$$\mathbf{W}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{\mathbf{C}(\mathbf{r'})}
{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}d^3r'\tag{3}$$

For a static electric field, $D=\dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ and $\mathbf{C}=0$. So, according to $(1)$ and $(2)$ the electric potential of **a charge distribution that goes to zero faster than $\dfrac{1}{r^2}$ as $r\to \infty$** can be calculated as
$$\Phi(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int \frac{\rho(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}d^3r'$$
where the integral is over all of space.

$\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}$ can be expanded using spherical harmonics to obtain a multipole expansion. So the multipole expansion is valid only under the above conditions too.

If the above condition doesn't hold, you have to use the $(1)$ equation, i.e. you have to find $\mathbf{E}$ first and then perform the integration to find $\Phi$ (as in the case of an infinite uniformly charged wire).

Comment: Yes, actually I am looking at an exponentially decaying charge distribution(so fast decaying) and now my question would be: What would be the correct expansion(of the denominator in harmonic function) if you are looking at the potential inside a sphere, when the charge distribution is only nonzero outside the sphere?

Comment: my question is, whether the expansion $\frac{1}{|r-r'|} = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{r'^l}{r^{l+1}}P_l(\cos(\theta))$, where r' is the interior position, where I want to know the potential. Is this correct, so can I integrate $\Phi(r',\theta) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 } \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \rho(r, \theta) \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{r'^l}{r^{l+1}}P_l(\cos(\theta)) d \phi d \theta dr$

Comment: sorry forgot the $r^2 \sin(\theta)$ and I think there is something wrong with my $\theta$ dependence, as I integrate over it, this one is somehow lost

Comment: Your expansion gives the potential on the $z$ axis. To find the potential everywhere, replace $\theta$ with $\gamma$, which is the angle between $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r'}$; i.e. expand in terms of spherical harmonics ([here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72660/potential-of-a-dipole-with-actual-physical-extension/72672#72672)).

Comment: but we do not have any dependence on $\phi$-dependence. is it not true that in this case the spherical harmonics reduce to the legendre polynomials?

Comment: In this case you should use $\mathrm{P}(\cos (\theta' - \theta))$ instead of $\mathrm{P}(\cos \theta)$.

Comment: so could you give me the integral that I need to evaluate, in order to be sure that we are talking about the same?

Comment: I probably thought about for the potential inside($r' \le R$) a spherical charge distribution $$ \rho(r,\theta)=0, r\le R, \rho(r,\theta) \neq 0 $$ elsewhere, $$  \Phi(r',\theta') = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 } \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \rho(r,\theta) \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{r^{'l}}{r^{l+1}}P_l(\cos(\theta) P_l(\cos(\theta')) \sin(\theta) r^2 dr d\theta d\phi$$

Comment: if this is wrong, please correct me!

Comment: Just replace $\mathrm{P_l}(\cos \theta)$ with $\mathrm{P_l}(\cos (\theta-\theta'))$. Then you should expand it in terms of spherical harmonics to become able to perform the integration . Instead, there exist an easier way to avoid this tedious integrations: find the potential on the z axis (use $\mathrm{P_l}(\cos \theta)$) and then compare the result with the solution of the Laplace equation in spherical coordinates (azimuthal symmetric solution) on the points on the z axis. This way, you can find the coefficients of the expansion and generalize the result to all of space.

Comment: sorry, can you write down the correct equation? I mean I have now two terms that contain Legendre polynomials with dependence of an angle there in my equation. Now I do not know, whether I should only use one of them and replace this one with the one that depends on the difference of the angles or whether I should keep both and replace only one of them or whether I should replace both?

Comment: We know the solution of Laplace equation (azimuthal):$$\Phi(r,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty(A_lr^l+B_lr^{-(l+1)})\mathrm{P_l}(\cos \theta)\tag{1}$$ Now, use $$\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{r_<^l}{r>^{(l+1)}}\mathrm{P_l}(\cos \theta)\tag{2}$$ in the integral for the potential in the answer, which gives the potential on the z axis. Now if you put $\theta=0$ in $(1)$ you will get the potential on the z axis. If you compare this result with the result of using $(2)$, you can obtain $A_l$s and $B_l$s and replace this coefficients in $(1)$ to obtain the potential for all space.

Comment: thank you, got it. just for curiosity. would this method also work to get the electric field somewhere inside the charge distribution? cause in this case one would have to consider that there is a contribution from the inside and the outside. so i would split this up in those two parts and do the same? ( i would mind the interchange of the r and r' in (2))

Comment: Yes, it works. (as you said, you should consider interchanging $r_<$ and $r_>$ when necessary).

Answer (score 3):

The most general expression for the potential (assuming a static charge distribution, as you use) is:

$$V({\vec r}) = C + \int d^{3}r'\frac{\rho({\vec r'})}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}\left|{\vec r}-{\vec r}'\right|}$$

Where C satisfies ${\vec \nabla}C = 0$, and the integral covers the region where $\rho \neq 0$.

If you doubt this, you can work out that $\nabla^{2} \frac{1}{\left|{\vec r}\right|} = \delta^{3}({\vec r})$, and then it should be pretty obvious that this equation satisfies the differential form of Gauss's law.

EDIT:

I see that you're asking what happens inside a gap inside of a spherically symmetric distribution.  In this case, you can use the high school physics version of Gauss's law to show that:

$$\left|{\vec E}\right| = k\frac{Q_{inc}}{r^{2}}$$

Since, inside of your inner gap, the charge enclosed by any gaussian surface is zero, you have $E = 0$ and $V=$ Constant

Comment: no, the first version was okay, but I was wondering how one can find C from your definition and whether there is some taylor expansion (of the denominator) that I could use in this case, since it is hard to integrate this thing in general

Comment: @Lipschitz: The potential is arbitrary, and C reflects this arbitrariness.  Typically, you specify one point where the potential is zero, and after you've done the integral, you evaluate the potential at this point, and set C such that the potential is zero here.

Comment: As far as evaluating the integral, you're probably safer doing a taylor expansion of the density in powers of $r-r'$, which should be nice easy integrals.  Most people just resort to numerics as this point.

Comment: The first equation you've provided for $V$ is not the most general. @Lipschitz asks for the most general case.

Comment: @Mostafa: that is the most general solution to Maxwell's equations in the static gauge in the case where $\rho$ is time-independent, which is the only reasonable way of answering the question.  It's certainly the most general solution to Poisson's equation.  If you want to write your own answer that tackles the time-dependence and a general gauge, have at it.  That's way beyond the scope of the question, and Jefemienko's equations aren't very enlightening.  Downvoting over that is petty.

Comment: I posted another answer.